# How to serialize MFC collections using boost

Tags: boost, mfc, boost-serialization

I'm trying to use Boost serialization in my MFC based project so far I had no luck whatsoever but getting error likes that *serialize is not a member of CArray* or *serialize is not a member of CMap* .

I cannot figure out how to serialize MFC collection .

Can any one come with a code that successfully serialize and deserialize MFC collection(CString ,CMap) using Boost API .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't have control over the CArray and CMap classes/templates, You will want to work from the [non-intrusive instructions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html#nonintrusiveversion).  In short, overload a serialize() free function that takes your class and stores the inner elements within it.  Depending on the contents of the array or map, you may need to write a further serialize<>() function for them.